# Boolean function to Algebraic Normal Form

Tags: finite-fields, boolean-algebra, cryptography, coding-theory

What is the Algorithm for getting truth table for the Boolean function (Near bent or semi bent functions)?\

Example: If I have a Boolean function over $\mathbb{F}_{2^5}$, how to write the function $f(x)=Tr((x)^{3})$ in truth table manually. Is there any algorithm for it or we have the inbuilt function in Java.

Comment: I suggest to make an example to clarify your question or cite it.

Comment: The current Question essays a condition of a Boolean function "without truth table" while the proposed duplicate assumes truth tables are available.  This distinction seems unmotivated here, as whatever form a Boolean function is expressed, computing the truth table for it should be an easy computation.  If the OP is serious about avoiding truth tables, the reason for this should have been included in the body of the Question.  That said, the theory of ANF over fields should provide a starting point to develop algorithms with other representations.

Comment: Will you please explain to me how to write the truth table for the Boolean function of the type Tr(x^3) over the field \mathbb{F_2^5}